# How to write a module with dynamic SSL Certificate in nginx？

Tags: ssl, nginx

I'm using nginx 1.16.0, and now there's a scenario where there's a part of server name that needs to load different SSL certificates. For some reasons, I can't use OpenResty, so I need to write modules to implement this function.

Now I think of two options.
1. Setting custom variables for ssl_certificate and other related instructions, writing a module can judge the server name and selectively modify the variable dynamically, so as to achieve the effect of dynamic certificate

`set $certificate_var '';  #Create custom variables
set $certificate_key_var '';
GetCertificateWithUpdateVariable 'certificate_var' 'certificate_key_var';#Modify the values of custom variables according to business logic within the custom module
ssl_certificate      $certificate_var;
ssl_certificate_key  $certificate_key_var;`

2. Modifying the source code of nginx about ssl, adding the judgment conditions directly to the source code, and recompiling on this basis.

I started to implement these two schemes, but I had problems.

The first solution: ssl_certificate does not support user-defined variables, nginx began to support some built-in variables after version 1.15.9, these variables can be added to the ssl_certificate instruction, but this is a bit fixed, I can not do something with judgment, so this idea can not meet my needs. Demand.

`ssl_certificate      /root/ssl/$ssl_server_name/fullchain.cer;
ssl_certificate_key  /root/ssl/$ssl_server_name/nginx.kooboo.cn.key;`

So can other ideas bypass this limitation?
1. Instead of modifying the custom variables, the ssl_certificate instruction itself is obtained directly in the module and modified. Is this feasible? How to do it?
2. Is it feasible to modify the value of $ssl_server_name in the module? How to do it?

The second solution is to modify the source code of nginx about ssl. The source code of nginx is huge. I can't find the core part of ssl. Logically, it should be an HTTP request coming in and loading the corresponding certificate after judging the server name. This link should be a key-value pair search process, I want to change the process of this block now, I want to manage this key-value pair by myself, so as to control his search.
Is this part easy to implement? Which part of the code should I modify?

I look forward to your reply.thanks

Answer (score 1):

I haven't logged in for a while, but I have already implemented this function. Here's a record: you only need to change the SSL_CTX_set_cert_cb function registered in ngx_http_ssl_module.c

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Starting from this I managed to implement a full blown solution for automatic SSL renewal in nginx in real time (no downtime). I had unfortunately to patch and remove the default implementation but it works (not extremely complex).